# ASP.NET - Converting Text to an Image and Displaying on an ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, imagebutton, imageurl

I'm creating ImageButtons on an asp.net website. Sometimes, however, an image doesn't exist for the given text and in those cases, rather than display a 'broken image', I want to simply convert the string to an image and display *that*.

I've seen how to create a Bitmap/Image using C# and .NET from a text string, however, I'm not sure how to utilize this for an asp.net project. The ImageButton requires an ImageUrl...so what can I do when I'm trying to dynamically create the images? Is there a way to create them and save them someplace that I can then point to or a way to create and show the images that doesn't require their being saved?

Any tips on how this could be achieved would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly possible.

[Dynamically Generating and Caching Images in ASP.NET with the GeneratedImage Control](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111734/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/042209-1.aspx)

Comment: That certainly looks like it'd solve my problem. Having never used VB, I'm a bit scared, but I'll read through the page and see if I can get something similar going with C#.

Comment: VB to C# is fairly straight forward. I used to be a VB.NET developer for 6 years then have been c# for 4 years. (much prefer c#). 

Tips: semi colon and everything is in reverse. Otherwise just google VB to C# translator. They are are heaps out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `LinkButton` instead.  You can use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) to see if the file exists, you may have to use [VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150163.aspx) if you need to find the applications path to that file.  If the file does not exist, you can set the `LinkButton`s value to just the name of the textual representation, otherwise you can put an image tag (hopefully with its alt attribute set).

Answer (score 0):

It's not generally considered good practice, but you could easily add a reference to Windows Forms and use GDI+. I've done this many times. Here's a link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1827/Web-Graphics-On-The-Fly-in-ASP-NET